# Symfony2 custom authentication method

Tags: php, security, authentication, symfony, hash

I'm trying to set up a custom authentication method along the lines of:

users table: id, username, email, hash2, salt1
passwords table: hash1, salt2

The method of authentication would then be:

- Retrieve salt1 and hash2 from the users table
- Retrieve salt2 from the passwords table (select salt2 where hash1 = hash(salt1 + password))
- Verify the password hashed with salt2 matches hash2

However, I can't figure out how to implement a multi-step authentication method like this. All examples I've found only show how the basic methods work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need to create your own authentication method ? Currently you're trying to do cryptography yourself, which is bad because cryptography is hard.

Is it possible for you to use the default authentication mechanism with your own user provider ? See documentation here http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html

Comment: Maybe I don't understand how Symfony2 works yet. Is there a way to do the above with the default authentication? The reason I want to do the above is it makes cracking a password difficult if anyone were to get their hands on the database. The only problem is, I can't see how I can use this with the getPassword and getSalt methods, as it's a multi-step method.

Comment: Don't worry default Symfony2 authentication mechanism is secure and passwords are hashed correctly.

Comment: I decided to go for this as implementing my own wasn't cost effective.